# How to customize disclosure cell in view-based NSOutlineView

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, nsoutlineview, disclosure

I'm trying to customize the disclosure arrow appearance in my view-based NSOutlineView. I saw that it's recommended to use

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayOutlineCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
```

delegate method to achieve it. The problem is that this method is not called for some reason. I have 2 custom cell views - one for item and second for header item. May be this method is not called for view-based outline views? May be something became broken in Lion?

Please shed some light.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*This answer is written with OS X 10.7 in mind, for newer versions of OS X/macOS, refer to [WetFish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20454413/644348)*

That method does not get called because it is only relevant for cell based outline views.

In a view based outline view, the disclosure triangle is a regular button in the row view of expandable rows. I don't know where it gets added, but it does, and `NSView`'s `didAddSubview:` method handles exactly that situation of a view being added somewhere else.

Hence, subclass `NSTableRowView`, and override `didAddSubview:`, like this:

```
-(void)didAddSubview:(NSView *)subview
{
    // As noted in the comments, don't forget to call super:
    [super didAddSubview:subview];

    if ( [subview isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]] ) {
        // This is (presumably) the button holding the 
        // outline triangle button.
        // We set our own images here.
        [(NSButton *)subview setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"disclosure-closed"]];
        [(NSButton *)subview setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"disclosure-open"]];
    }
}
```

Of course, your outline view's delegate will have to implement `outlineView:rowViewForItem:` to return the new row view.

Despite the name, `frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:` of `NSOutlineView` still gets called for view based outline views, so for the positioning of your triangle, you might want to subclass the outline view and override that method, too.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So the outlineView:rowViewForItem basically will replace the outlineView:viewForTableColumn in case of expandable cells?

Comment: I guess it depends how you want to do it. I use both, the row view to draw the background (and the disclosure triangle, as it happens) and the cell view for the contents. I believe that is also how it is intended, but views are flexible by nature.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you very much! On the apple list they suggested to fill a bug on both - absence of proper customizing interface and poor documentation on this.

Comment: don't forget to call [super didAddSubview:] -- otherwise, your going to have some trouble...

Answer (score 33):

#### Solution 1:

Subclass NSOutlineView and override `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:`

```
- (id)makeViewWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier owner:(id)owner {
    id view = [super makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:owner];

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey]) {
        // Do your customization
    }

    return view;
}
```

For Source Lists use `NSOutlineViewShowHideButtonKey`.

#### Solution 2:

**Interface Builder**

The button is added to the column and the identifier set to `NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey`.

[image]

#### Official documentation from `NSOutlineView.h`

```
/* The following NSOutlineView*Keys are used by the View Based NSOutlineView to create the "disclosure button" used to collapse and expand items. The NSOutlineView creates these buttons by calling [self makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:] passing in the key as the identifier and the delegate as the owner. Custom NSButtons (or subclasses thereof) can be provided for NSOutlineView to use in the following two ways:
 1. makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: can be overridden, and if the identifier is (for instance) NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey, a custom NSButton can be configured and returned. Be sure to set the button.identifier to be NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey.
 2. At design time, a button can be added to the outlineview which has this identifier, and it will be unarchived and used as needed.
 
 When a custom button is used, it is important to properly set up the target/action to do something (probably expand or collapse the rowForView: that the sender is located in). Or, one can call super to get the default button, and copy its target/action to get the normal default behavior.
 
 NOTE: These keys are backwards compatible to 10.7, however, the symbol is not exported prior to 10.9 and the regular string value must be used (i.e.: @"NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey").
 */
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *const NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9); // The normal triangle disclosure button
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *const NSOutlineViewShowHideButtonKey NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9); // The show/hide button used in "Source Lists"
```

Comment: What happens where you have `//Do your customization`?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum That's up to you. You can modify `view` (NSButton created by superclass) or create and return your own view. But be sure to set the identifier if you create your own view.

Comment: e.g. `[(NSButton *)view setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"disclosure-closed"]];`

Comment: This is helpful but I only want to customize the disclosure button for the first row. How can I determine the row or item for the view being requested as this request is not generated by the delegate's `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` method but by the outlineView's private `_updateDisclosureButtonForRowView:forRow:removeIfNotAvailable:updatePosition:inDidAddRowView:` method.

Answer (score 8):

For Swift 4.2 macOS 10.14, @WetFish's answer can be implemented as follows:

```swift
class SidebarView: NSOutlineView {

  override func makeView(withIdentifier identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier, owner: Any?) -> NSView? {
    let view = super.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: owner)

    if identifier == NSOutlineView.disclosureButtonIdentifier {
      if let btnView = view as? NSButton {
        btnView.image = NSImage(named: "RightArrow")
        btnView.alternateImage = NSImage(named: "DownArrow")

        // can set properties of the image like the size
        btnView.image?.size = NSSize(width: 15.0, height: 15.0)
        btnView.alternateImage?.size = NSSize(width: 15.0, height: 15.0)
      }
    }
    return view
  }

}
```

Looks quite nice!

[image]

Comment: I followed your answer and I was able to add custom separator. But I am getting a separator line between each group. How do I remove that?

Answer (score 2):

Swift2 version of @Monolo's answer:

```
override func didAddSubview(subview: NSView) {
    super.didAddSubview(subview)
    if let sv = subview as? NSButton {
        sv.image = NSImage(named:"icnArwRight")
        sv.alternateImage = NSImage(named:"icnArwDown")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - now we just need a Swift version of WetFish's answer!

Comment: You're a gangster, Thanks!
New method name:
`func didAddSubview(_ subview: NSView)`