# Always show disclosure triangle in NSOutlineView even for empty entries

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, appkit

I have an app that shows "chapters and pages" in an `NSOutlineView`.

To make it clear to the user that "chapters" can contain "pages", I'd like the outline view to always show the disclosure triangle for chapters, even if they have no pages in them (i.e. are empty).

Here's an example:

[image]

Note how the first chapter is empty (no pages) and has *no* disclosure triangle.

I'd like the triangle to show up so that when users click on it, they realize that this is a "container" item that can contain other items.

I tried implementing various delegate methods, but could not get the disclosure triangle to show for empty entries.

Sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdggjod78t0isjr/OutlineViewTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: How did you implement `- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item` NSOutlineView delegate method?

Comment: I implemented `isItemExpandable:` to return YES all the time. However, it is not called for items with no children.

Comment: Can you provide your code? I'm interested in `NSOutlineViewDataSource` methods.

Comment: @Astoria I added a link to the sample project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now I see. You're using Cocoa Bindings which assumes that some of the `dataSource` methods shouldn't get called. As displayed at the [NSOutlineViewDataSource reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSOutlineViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html)

> '- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
>      isItemExpandable:(id)item'
>
> IMPORTANT
>
> While this method is marked as @optional in the protocol, you must implement this method if you are not providing the data for the outline view using Cocoa bindings.

Just try to implement it without Cocoa Bindings. Or you can find the way to break into the binding process and find out how to reject disclosure button deletion.

Yep, there's a third way. You can create MyTableCellView.xib and add your own disclosure button as well.

**UPD**

To determine, which item should have disclosure triangle, there's a `Leaf` key path at the `Tree Controller` attributes inspector tab.

[image]

Don't forget to add models' values to your data like that

```
@{@"title": @"Chapter 1 (empty)", @"isLeaf":@(NO)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Implementing without bindings is not really an option as this would make my app more complicated (it's a fairly large app already). Adding my own button might work, but also does not seem quite right. I'm still hoping that there's a way through extending NSOutlineView or some delegate method...

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `NSOutlineViewDelegate` `outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:` and have it return YES.

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:(id)item {
    return YES;
}
```

The "outline cell" is the disclosure triangle.   You need this *in addition to* returning YES for `isExpandable`.

The [method's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSOutlineViewDelegate/outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:) says:

> Returning NO causes `frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:` to return `NSZeroRect`

And [the 1st answer here about how to change the triangle image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127764/how-to-customize-disclosure-cell-in-view-based-nsoutlineview) seems to indicate that the *frame* gets used for both cell and view-based outline views, so this method should work for both.  (Note that the easier solution is the 2nd answer there.)

This answer is wiki... I suspect I missed something.