# Custom disclosure view NSOutlineView Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have two questions here. First I wanted a custom image for disclosure so I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51121343/2287422). But I don't know why I get a separator between each group. I don't want a separator. I need it to be as need as in the above answer. Now to the second question, I want to add some spacing before the disclosure. How do I do that? Attaching a image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: Sure but both are minor and related questions so thought of asking together. Any help to solve the problem?

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: Just create a simple outline view with 2 levels. You will see a divider and different color for group row. I don't want both. If i add the code here, i would end up adding all the outline view data source and delegate methods.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but it looks like the image in the linked answer. Is the question about group rows? What is the size of the image? Is the image a template? Is your implentation of `makeView(withIdentifier:owner:)` exactly the same as in the linked answer? What is the row height? Did you replace the default row view or cell view? Any changes to the Xcode `NSOutlineView` template? Any relevant delegate methods?