# How to add a plus button next to the disclosure button for group row in NSOutlineView?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview, nsbutton, nstablecellview

I would like to add a button next to the disclosure button like in `Mail.app`.

[image: A screen recording of Mail.app sidebar]

And I don't want to do it like this in `Photos.app`.

[image: A screen recording of Photos.app sidebar]

I had a look at the [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127764/how-to-customize-disclosure-cell-in-view-based-nsoutlineview) but they are about customising existing disclosure buttons which I do not wish to modify. I just want to add a button next to it and not for every group item. I believe it has to be done programmatically.

I tried adding a button on storyboard and place it on the right of the `NSTableCellView` and the disclosure button overlap it. So I think it should not be done on storyboard.